# Blank fields issues

Tags: php, html, forms

I've noticed that when I deliberately try to mess up the form by not entering the required fields, it works the first time (ie, it triggers the error messages). But when I try to fill in the rest of missing fields, and hit submit, the form shows up again blank.

Or if I miss a field, and then try to enter in the missing field (has triggered error), and deliberately blank out another field before submitting, again the form shows up blank. Why?!?!?!

(I'm truly awful at PHP. So, please go slow with me.)

**PHP Form**

```
<?php
    session_start(); //allows use of session variables


    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && $_SESSION['token'] == $_POST['token'] && !empty($_SESSION['token'])) {

       if (empty($_POST["first-name"])) {
         $firstNameErr = "First name is required";
       } else {
         $first_name = test_input($_POST["first-name"]);
       }

        if (empty($_POST["last-name"])) {
         $lastNameErr = "Last name is required";
       } else {
         $last_name = test_input($_POST["last-name"]);
       }

       if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
         $emailErr = "Email is required";
       } else {
         $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
       }

       if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
         $messageErr = "Message is required";
       } else {
         $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
       }


       if(isset($first_name) && isset($last_name) && isset($email) && isset($message))
       {
         $_SESSION['first_name'] = $first_name;
         $_SESSION['last_name'] = $last_name;
         $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
         $_SESSION['message'] = $message;
         header("Location: contact9SessionsCRSF2.php");
         exit; 
       }
    }
    else {
      $token = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
      $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
      $_SESSION['token_time'] = time();
    }

    function test_input($data) {
       $data = trim($data);
       $data = stripslashes($data);
       $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
       return $data;
    }
    ?>
```

**HTML Form**

```
  <form class="form-horizontal"  method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

  <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">First Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" name="first-name" id="first-name" placeholder="First Name" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($first_name)) { echo $first_name; }?>">
       <?php if(isset($firstNameErr)) print ('<span class="error">* ' . $firstNameErr . '</span>'); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Last Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" name="last-name" id="last-name" placeholder="Last Name" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($last_name)) { echo $last_name; }?>">
       <?php if(isset($lastNameErr)) print ('<span class="error">* ' . $lastNameErr . '</span>'); ?>
     </div>
    </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" >
       <?php if(isset($emailErr)) print ('<span class="error">* ' . $emailErr . '</span>'); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" placeholder="Please type in your message" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
       <?php if(isset($messageErr)) print ('<span class="error">* ' . $messageErr . '</span>'); ?>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you upload a demo?

Comment: what do you mean shows up 'blank' ? do you have display_errors enabled in your php.ini?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're not setting `$token` when you go into the `if` block that does all the input validation. But then when you redisplay the form, you use `$token` in the value of the hidden input. As a result, this input field is empty the next time you submit the form, so the `if` test at the beginning fails and you don't do any input processing.

Put

```
$token = $_SESSION['token'];
```

somewhere in that block.

Also, in the `if`, you should check `!empty($_SESSION['token'])` before comparing it with `$_POST['token']`. Otherwise, if it's not set you'll try to access an undefined index. So it should be:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && !empty($_SESSION['token']) && $_SESSION['token'] == $_POST['token']) {
```

Comment: thank you! I'm still confused over the quality of my php code but that's for later time when I'll review over it again. But what you pointed out worked. So ... thank you again, and happy holidays!